# Retain jquery appended input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<select>
    <option>Select people</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
</select>

<p>
<div id="names"></div>
</p>
</form>
<script>
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $("#names").html('')
  var count=$(this).val()
   
  var str='';
  for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
    str+='<input type="text"><br/><br/>'
  }
  
  $("#names").append(str)
  
});


</script>
```

The appended input field is not retaining after page refresh or on coming back from next page. How should i reatin input fields and autopopulate input fields on refresh

Comment: Store the value somewhere in a persistent storage, such as `localStorage` and you can fetch it even on a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can do something like so.

> Store the value somewhere in a persistent storage, such as `localStorage` and you can fetch it even on a refresh.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $("#names").html('')
    var count=$(this).val()
    
    var str='';

    if (localStorage.getItem("str") !== null) {
        str = localStorage.getItem("str");
    }

    for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
      str+='<input type="text"><br/><br/>'
    }
    
    $("#names").append(str)
    
    localStorage.setItem("str", str);
});
```